Appending DWORD at the end of LPCWSTR
I was trying to append a DWORD variable at the end of a LPCWSTR in order to pass it to a CreateProcess as the command line argument, but I haven't found a way to do it.
My best guess is trying to concatenate it with a casting, like this:
wcsncat_s(string, (wchar_t *)id, 8);

8 is just to put something there, and id is the DWORD variable.
I appreciate any insight and will add any code you believe neccessary.

use std::wformat to format a C++ new string. LCPCWSTR windows_string;  std::wstring cpp_string = std::format("{}{}", windows_string, 8). In general use C++ types as much as you can and only on the boundaries to the windows API convert to "windows types". To use your std::wstring on a windows api use cpp_string.c_str()

Don't you want to pass the decimal string representation of the value? If so, you'll need something like sprintf in C. If not, you'll have problems because the internal representation of many values contain NUL characters, which are a no go in command line arguments.

I think you need rather wsprintf, something like wsprintf (string, "%s,%d", string, id). Also this conversion is wrong from all and any points of view (wchar_t *)id. Make sure your string contains enough memory to hold the final string. Also wcsncat_s can concatenate only strings.

Only tag the language you are using. Don't tag both C and C++. Please fix immediately by removing the inappropriate tag.

Since you tagged as C++, you use std::ostringstream to print to a std::string, then use std::string::data() to create a lcpcwstr.

Since you tagged as C, you would use sprintf or one of its relatives, to print to a character array, hoping that the array is big enough to contain the formatted string.  Note:  The C language does not have the std::string type.

Tactical note: remember that when adding to a C-style string, you must first make absolutely certain you have enough storage in the string to hold the extra content you want to add. The string will not extend itself or otherwise size itself to fit. If C++ is an option, build the string up in a std::wstring, which does size itself, and use the c_str or data methods to get the constructed string as a c-style string.

@user4581301 does data() guarantee a null terminator on the string?  I'd be very careful with that one.

The C in LPCWSTR means it's a constant string and can't be changed. But you can create a new one.

@MarkRansom As of C++11, when data was added, the string's internal buffer is required to be contiguous and null terminated.

After fiddling a bit with the code and different suggestions (I'm really sorry about using more than one language in the tags), thanks to armagedescu, I solved this.
wsprintf (string2, "%s %d", string, id)

Thank you so much!

I will be very impressed if wsprintf supports using the same string as both an input and the output. I think you are getting lucky here because of the ordering. wsprintf will be updating string with itself as it processes string and you'll probably get away with that, but if you did pretty much anything else, for example if you swapped the ordering and inserted id first, string would have likely been at least partly overwritten when used and would be updating itself as it is being used. A really bad scene.

Unfortunately, Microsoft is stuck in the last century and doesn't seem to supply restrict keywords on function prototypes - even those that have arguments specified with the restrict keyword like char *strcpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2); (and no, strcpy() is not "deprecated" no matter how often nor how sternly Microsoft lies to you...).  Without that we can't conclude that overlapping input and output aren't supported.  But of course we can't conclude that overlapping input and output are supported either.

(cont) "But it works for me!" is, at best, very shallow thinking.  Not observing a failure does not mean it works all the time.  That'd be like watching a busy highway for a few seconds, not seeing a crash, and concluding automobile accidents can't happen.

Yes, you're right, I used two separate strings, I just forgot to put it in there, I was thinking of it more like a demonstration, I will edit it right now.

Regardless of what wsprintf demands, you can't write to a LPCWSTR anyway. You'd need a WCHAR[ ].
